# MYSQL count number of neighboring entries for each row

Tags: mysql, gis, nearest-neighbor

I have mysql table with the columns Id,latitude (DOUBLE),longitude (DOUBLE), price(DOUBLE) of about 40k entries. Now I want to calculate for each row how many entries are within a certain neighborhood (e.g. 5 km radius) and what is the average price of this neighborhood. 
So the result should be in the form:

```
Id  | COUNT | AVG(price)
---------------------
1   | 5     | 5.9
---------------------
2   | 11    | 11.2
```

..

I can use the circle distance formula to find neighbors within a certain distance of a fixed point but how can I do this for every row?
Alternative a solution using mysql GIS or even python is also ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have your distancefunction, lets call it `greatcircledistance()`, it is pretty straight forward to do this for every row:

```
select a.id, count(b.id), avg(b.price)
from mytable a 
left join mytable b 
on greatcircledistance(a.latitude, a.longitude, b.latitude, b.longitude) <= 5
group by a.id;
```

For 40k entries, that should be acceptable fast (you can optimize it by only calculation the exact distance if the coordinates are close enough). Using geometry data and a spatial index will speed this up most significantly though.